# Have Subdirectory of site in IIS show the index.html file when browsing to site

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am a fairly novice windows IIS guy, so any help I would greatly appreciate.

I have a client that requested all root Urls on their department websites redirect to their index.html page. So if a user, for example, goes to https://mysite.domain.com/, it will redirect to https://mysite.doman.com/index.html.

I did this through IIS 10 using a URLrewrite rule on the root of each site by doing the following.

```
         <rule name="Index Request" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url="^$" />
             <action type="Redirect" url="https://mysite.domain.com/index.html" />
      </rule>
```

This seemed to work.

The client now wants to have any of the subfolders of the root site show the index.html to any subdirectory sites of the root. Example. Https://mysite.domain.com/subdir/ “This is what shows now” to https://mysite.domain.com/subdir/index.html. Is there a way to do this in IIS?

Thanks in advance for any advice

I have made sure the index.html is the default document. I have also looked at User Friendly URL-template https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/user-friendly-url-rule-template, but I am not sure if this is the right direction to go.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't GitHub, so the Markdown syntax is different. Make sure you study it and format the question body properly in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<rule name="SEF Rule" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html" matchType="IsFile" 
 ignoreCase="false" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/index.html" />
     </rule>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/index.html" />
</rule>

<rule name="test1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
     <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/([^/]+)" />
     </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="/{C:1}/index.html" />
</rule>
```

Comment: It seems to be redirecting but I am getting this error in the browser when to urls . This page isn’t working right now mysite.com redirected you too many times.
To fix this issue, try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. I did have another redirect rule that I removed but I still get this error message when browsing to url. I am sure it is something I am looking over any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I modified the matching parameters in the answer, you can try the above rule again.

Comment: Still getting the Err_Too_Many_Redirects. This is what I put in for the rule below.                                                                                                   <rules>
<rule name="Index Request" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^subdir/|$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>                                                                                               I also tried just putting /index in the URl= but got the same issue.  As you can tell I am a newbie with URL Rewrite

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, the redirected url should be `https://mysite.domain.com/{R:0}index.html`, I re-edited my answer, you can try it again.

Comment: I am still getting the Err_Too_Many_Redirects. This is what I have <rule name="Index Request" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^subdir/|$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://mysite.domain.com/{R:0}index.html" />
 </rule>   Am I going about this the right way? Wanting a user that goes to mysite.domain.com/ show as mysite.domain.com/index.html? Thanks for being so welling to give me advice.

Comment: I also noticed that when you go to mysite.domain.com/subfolder it redirects you to mysite.domain.com/index.html instead of mysite.domain.com/subfolder/index.html

Comment: If the requested url is `mysite.domain.com/subfolder`, then you need to change the rule, you can try the rule in the above answer.

Comment: Ok, so am I understanding you correctly that you would have to have a separate redirect rule for each subfolder that has a index.html file?  If that is the case is there a way to have anything that ends with / for example mysite.domain.com/ to append the file it is going to so it would go, or you would see the mysiste.domain.com/index.html full path in the URL? I may be looking at this all wrong.

Comment: I tried the update rule the site is coming up http://mysite.domain.com/ but not showing the index.html at the end.

Comment: `so am I understanding you correctly that you would have to have a separate redirect rule for each subfolder that has a index.html file?`  No, this mainly depends on whether your matching parameters and the redirected url can satisfy multiple conditions at the same time. If it can be satisfied at the same time, then only one rule is required.

Comment: ok, that is good to know this can be done. Thanks, again Samwu for helping me figure this out. You have been great guiding me through this.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If not, [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) might help you.

Comment: No the problem is not solved but I think your helping me under the question called Show Full URL path automictically when browsing. I will look into the failed request tracing as well. Sorry for the confusion I thought rewording my question may help. I guess not.

Comment: This should be the same question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74318815/show-full-url-path-automictically-when-browsing-iis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74318815/show-full-url-path-automictically-when-browsing-iis).